# If a pipe and redirection symbol are used what is the Execution flow of command in Batch?

Tags: batch-file

If `|` and `>` are both used in a single line of a batch file, what is the order of execution of the commands?

And what is the use of `\` in between `%3` and `%2` in the below example?

```
type "%3\%2.xml" | findstr /I /c:"<logfile>" > %TEMP%\_logfile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

"%3\%2.xml" represents the directory (%3) in where the xml file (%2) is. %3 and %2 are replaceable parameters, of a batch file or of a function inside the batch file. Their values will change depending of the call.

The order of execution of the rest of the line is something between "left to right" and "all at the same time". Processes are started in parallel, and output channel of one is redirected to the input channel of the next, ... until the final redirection to output file, with data flowing along the pipe. More or less. Depends of the precise commands. But it is the idea.